# Do I need to create a new package in magento enterprise?

Tags: magento

Is there any difference between creation new theme package in magento community and enterprise version? I see in `/design/frontend` new folder "enterprise" available now. I wonder where I have to create my own theme - in or out this folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Edition comes with additional functionality not found in community. Because of this instead of creating a new blank package you must **duplicate the enterprise package**. Rename it to whatever you want and **keep the default theme and files inside that package**. This will overwrite the standard Magento files with the Enterprise version. You then **create a theme variant** in this folder so that the default folder copied from Enterprise can be used as a fallback.

It's a bit messy and apparently will be fixed in a future release but as of EEv1.8 this is the recommended method.

You can read more about it on [the Magento Site](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magentos-theme-hierarchy) under the FAQ *'What About default/default?'*, and then *'2nd Exception to Rule 6'* and also read more in the [Magento Design Guide PDF](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf) at the very end of *Chapter 3*.

Answer (score 0):

Actually No, Enterprise edition have one extra package called **enterprise** and have default and iphone theme.

I you check `System->Configuration->GENERAL->Design` you will found that package name is set to **enterprise**.

So you can create your own Package and Theme in the same way as in Magento Community. for reference you can use [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/0_-_theming_in_magento/package) link.